# combine allure reports from several machines into one without retry

Tags: jenkins, pytest, allure

I ask you to consult on the following question about allure: I use jenkins + pytest to run the tests. The same tests run on several virtual machines, these machines differ in operating systems (different linux distributions) and test environment. After running the tests, I want to combine the results from all the machines into one report. - here the question arises - if I put all the reports in one directory and generate a report, then the results from different machines will be considered as rerun of the same test and combined into one. How can I get around this? so as not to be combined and so that it was possible to somehow sort out which result from which machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i have solve this by override the names of tests/suites.
Meaning you have to make some code implementation, work with the before listeners, there you can get the current test name and override it. Set the test name by OS + Browser or something unique.

When you combine reports, they will be unique and properly displayed.

Comment: tell me how in the tests themselves (in fixture) you can change the name of the tests? which hook to use?

Comment: as i said you can use the "before" hooks. Before each test start, before each suite start etc...

Comment: This looks interesting. Can you please provide the sample listener?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with behave where Allure was treating each parallel build as a retry of the first build.  I realize this isn't the same as pytest, but perhaps it'll help.

I was inspired by the previous answer and started experimenting.  By changing the scenario name(s) within the feature, I was able to make Allure recognize each parallel build as separate tests.  I accomplished this by adding a `before_feature` method to my environment.py file that simply added the hostname to each scenario name within that feature:

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
    for scenario in feature.scenarios:
        scenario.name = f'[{socket.gethostname()}] {scenario.name}'
```

Originally, I tried to directly change `scenario.name` in `before_scenario` but that seemed to have no effect in Allure.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pytest_addoption` to define additional parameters for capturing device names, and add `pytest_collection_modifyitems` in `conftest.py` to modify the names of tests/suites.

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
  parser.addoption("--udid", action="store", help="UDID of the device")


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
  for item in items:
      udid = config.getoption("--udid")
      item.name = udid
      item._nodeid = udid
```